# Java LinkedHashSet remove(Object obj) method constant/linear time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

In the docs, it is stated that

> Like HashSet, [LinkedHashSet] provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (add, contains and **remove**), assuming the hash function disperses elements properly among the buckets.

I understand how HashSet can provide constant-time performance for remove(Object obj), but since LinkedHashSet needs to maintain a linked list as well, and removing a specific element involves traversing the list, then it seems to me that remove(Object obj) should take linear time. Am I missing anything?

The only explanation I can think of is that each entry in the hash table (maintained by LinkedHashSet) contains a reference to the corresponding node in the linked list, so it takes constant time to locate the node in the linked list. But I am not sure if it is really the implementation...

Thanks!

Comment: Removing a specific element that you have already located via its hash code is *O(1)*. Just a matter of adjusting two links. Each entry in the hash table *is* the corresponding node in the linked list.

Comment: "and removing a specific element involves traversing the list" - Nope, because the hash table entry points you straight to the linked list node you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LinkedHashSet` maintains links between the nodes in addition to the hash table. It is not necessary to traverse the  whole list for removal, only the list neighbors need to be updated. Accessing a specific element is no more expensive than for the `HashSet`.